# Installing Unity3D with Wine

Tags: unity, wine, playonlinux

So I've been trying to install Unity using the famous scripts by Cauê and Tomza which failed. I just installed without the scripts and it installed though visual studio and VSTU failed. I tried to install visual studio separately but it didn't work. I launches unity anyway and got an error: 
Error initializing license system

Here is what I got in Debug mode:

```
[05/14/16 19:07:38] - Running wine-1.7.16 Unity.exe (Working directory : /home/exos9/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Unity3D/drive_c/Program Files/Unity/Editor)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryerr:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
```

So that's where I'm at. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

## Unity is providing official support for Ubuntu

To download the latest version, scroll down to the last post on the thread: [Unity on Linux: Release Notes and Known Issues](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)

After download, to install see: [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/841370/538619)

Comment: The problem is, when I tried that it crashed upon startup. Also, I need to install unity on a secondary drive as I am lacking disk space

Comment: And also, the Linux version CAN'T import models from third party apps like Blender on which I've already modelled about 4 complex models